# PUT and GET with $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb

I try to rewrite information with $.ajax and show all on the display. 
It is about PUT and GET information from MongoDB. 
First I do PUT colunms of table with $.ajax in MongoDB.
$.ajax with PUT is good working, because I see, that all is edited in MongoDB. 
After this action I want to get  information  from database. And here I have fail.
I do not understand, why after PUT I get not actual information from data base.

```
$.ajax({
    url: VASERVER_API_LOC + '/visualization/' + visid + '/',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(features),
    type: 'PUT',
    success: function (data) {

    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: VASERVER_API_LOC + '/visualization/' + visid + '/',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: tmp_object,
    success: function (tmp_object) {
        var features = tmp_object.features;...
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax runs *asynchronously* (that's part of its name).  What that means is that the two calls to `$.ajax` may not complete in any order -- or ever complete.

If you have code that relies on the result of an asynchronous call, all work that relies on the call needs to be done in the *callback* for the ajax.  The callback is fired after the ajax completes.  You could use `success`, or use deferreds (built in):

```
$.ajax(putRequest).done(function () {
    $.ajax(getRequest);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is **asynchronous**, so that second AJAX call is running before your `PUT` is completed, wrap that in a function, and call that from the `success` of the first:

```
$.ajax({
    url: VASERVER_API_LOC + '/visualization/' + visid + '/',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(features),
    type: 'PUT',
    success: function (data) {
        getData();
    }
});

function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: VASERVER_API_LOC + '/visualization/' + visid + '/',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: tmp_object,
        success: function (tmp_object) {
            var features = tmp_object.features;...
        }
     })
}
```